# jetpack compose resource.getDimension and dimensionResource have different value. Why did jetpack compose team do it that way

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-xml

I am converting an existing view to jetpack compose. I found out that `dimensionResource()` is different from `resources.getDimension()`. Why is that? I know that the code for `dimensionResource()` is dividing the `resources.getDimension()` by screen density. The issue I have is that we can't really convert everything on our app to jetpack compose. We are slowly converting it but that would take a while. Because the result are different, we will have to provide a new dimension sp for jetpack compose which is weird as I thought that compose work well with view xml and vice versa. Perhaps what I wanted to know is that why did jetpack compose team decided to make the `dimensionResource()` different from that one we would normally use for view xml? This adds more confusion. Example

```
Column {
        Text("Using context.resources")
        Text("Testing", fontSize = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.test).sp)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
        Text("Using dimensionResource")
        Text("Testing", fontSize = dimensionResource(R.dimen.test).value.sp)
}
```

Result is

[image]